# How to avoid Typeerror when sorting dates and grouping them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe like as shown below

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Adm DateTime':['02/25/2012 09:40:00','03/05/1996 09:41:00','11/12/2010 10:21:21','31/05/2012 04:21:31','21/07/2019 13:15:02','31/10/2020 08:21:00'],
                 's_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2],
                't_id':['t1','t2','t3','t3','t4','t5']})
df['Adm DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adm DateTime'])
```

I would like to generate row number based for each group (of s_id)

I tried the below

```
df['R_N'] = df.sort_values(['Adm DateTime'], ascending=True).groupby(['s_id']).cumcount() + 1
```

While this works in sample data, it throws below error in original data.

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime'
> and 'str'

But there is no `NA` in my original `Adm DateTime` column and the data type of the column itself is `datetime64[ns]`. I don't explicitly perform any comparison between dates (except sorting which may be done internally)

May I know why does this error happen and how can I identify the records which cause this issue?

Comment: A `datetime64[ns]` column should be holding `timestamps` not `datetime.datetime` objects, which makes me think your column is `Object` dtype.

Comment: what's the difference between `timestamps` and `datetime.datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try split solution because in your solution if chain sorting and creating new column pandas have to internally reorder rows by original index, I guess it should be problem here (and output has no sorted rows).

```
df['R_N'] = (df.sort_values(['Adm DateTime'], ascending=True)
               .groupby(['s_id']).cumcount() + 1)
print (df)
         Adm DateTime  s_id t_id  R_N
0 2012-02-25 09:40:00     1   t1    3
1 1996-03-05 09:41:00     1   t2    1
2 2010-11-12 10:21:21     1   t3    2
3 2012-05-31 04:21:31     1   t3    4
4 2019-07-21 13:15:02     2   t4    1
5 2020-10-31 08:21:00     2   t5    2
```

If need this output possible idea should be creating unique index values:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['R_N'] = (df.sort_values(['Adm DateTime'], ascending=True)
               .groupby(['s_id']).cumcount() + 1)
```

---

My solution after sort create new `DataFrame`, so no reorder or rows is necessary (and output has sorted rows)

```
df['Adm DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adm DateTime'])

df = df.sort_values(['Adm DateTime'])
df['R_N'] = df.groupby(['s_id']).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
         Adm DateTime  s_id t_id  R_N
1 1996-03-05 09:41:00     1   t2    1
2 2010-11-12 10:21:21     1   t3    2
0 2012-02-25 09:40:00     1   t1    3
3 2012-05-31 04:21:31     1   t3    4
4 2019-07-21 13:15:02     2   t4    1
5 2020-10-31 08:21:00     2   t5    2
```

Comment: Hi, one quick question. Is sorting the whole dataframe like you have shown (without group by subjects) is same as sorting the dataframe by grouping subject ids? Because I have to appky this logic on 10 million rows. Hence asking

Comment: upvoted. splitting the solution works. May I know how does it work when we split it?